# The following differential equation depends on a parameter $a$. Sketch the corresponding bifurcation diagram.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> The following differential equation depends on a parameter $a$. Sketch the corresponding bifurcation diagram.
>
> $$x' = x^3 - x + a$$

Our professor did not get to finish talking about this during lecture and I am trying to figure it out but I'm stuck and was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. From my understanding, in order to sketch a bifurcation diagram:

- You need to solve for $a$: $a = -x^3 + x$
- Then find the inverse of that in order to graph it
- In order to know what direction your arrows are pointing, you need to test some values using your equilibrium points

I am stuck on finding the inverse for $a$. I graphed $a$ and found the roots to be at $(0,1), (0, -1)$, and $(0,0)$ so I assumed the inverse points would be at $(-1, 0), (1, 0)$, and $(0,0)$ and sketched it using that. However, I can't figure out what inverse function graph passes through those points. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have also tried solving for $x$ using $x^3 - x + a = 0$ to try and find the equilibrium points and got $0, 1$, and $-1$ which I think are incorrect so any help with this would also be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: $a=0$ is a regular point with 3 simple isolated equilibria. What you want to examine are the extrema of $a(x)$ and closely around them, as the number of equilibria changes.

Comment: @Moo I have not unfortunately

Comment: @LutzLehmann how do I examine the extrema of a(x) if you don't mind me asking?

Answer (score 2):

We want to find the bifurcation diagram for (there is a nice theory write-up at [*LibreTexts*](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Applied_Linear_Algebra_and_Differential_Equations_(Chasnov)/03%3A_III._Differential_Equations/11%3A_Nonlinear_Differential_Equations/11.02%3A_Bifurcation_Theory)).

$$x' = x^3 - x + a$$

Let's get a qualitative idea of the behaviors using phase portraits for a few $a's$ and a bifurcation

**$a = -1$**

[image]

**$a = 0$**

[image]

**$a = 1$**

[image]

From these, we see that there a single unstable critical point at $a = -1$, three critical points, $x = -1, 0, 1$ (two unstable and one stable) at $a = 0$, and another single and unstable critical point at $a = 1$.

What happens if we make $a$ larger and smaller than one?

There is a description of these phase portraits at this [*Math Stack Exchange*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2633619/constructing-a-bifurcation-diagram-for-dotx-x3-x-lambda) answer (this answer is different because it adds phase portraits and a bifurcation diagram).

Now, let's draw a contour plot of $x'$ as $a$ versus $x$ to see these behaviors described by the portraits and the linked description.

[image]

Notice the behaviors and compare to the phase portraits. The green area is the stable area, and the red are unstable values of $a$.

Please fill in the details so you learn and determine the type of bifurcation.

Note, we can also draw the phase portraits like a phase-line, which is equivalent to looking at the sign of $x'$ on either side of the critical point .

**$a = -1$**

[image]

**$a = 0$**

[image]

**$a = 1$**

[image]

[*Here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2963026/bifurcation-diagram-confusion) is another example of this approach.

Comment: Thank you so much, I greatly appreciate it! This helped a lot!